# Should data being used by ActiveJob (resque) be persisted or put into a ruby object and passed by object id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, twilio, resque, rails-activejob

I am using Twilio to [send/receive texts in a Rails](https://www.twilio.com/docs/ruby/install) 4.2 app. I am sending in bulk, around 1000 at a time, and receiving sporadically.

Currently when I receive a text I save it to the DB (to, from, body) and then pass that record to an ActiveJob worker to process later. For sending messages I currently persist the Twilio params to another DB and pass that record to a different ActiveJob worker. Since I am often doing it in batches I have two workers. The first outgoing message worker sends a single message. The second one queries the DB and finds all the user who should receive the message, creates a DB record for each message that should be sent, and then passes that record to the first outgoing message worker. So the second one basically just creates a bunch of jobs for the first one to process.

Right now I have the workers destroying the records once they finish processing (both incoming and outgoing). I am worried about not persisting things incase the server, redis, or resque go down but I do not know if this is actually a good design pattern. It was suggested to me just to use a vanilla ruby object and pass it's id to the worker but I am not sure how that effects data reliability. So is it over kill to be creating all these DBs and should I just be creating vanilla ruby objects and passing those object's ids to the workers?

Any and all insight is appreciated,

Drew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the approach of sending a minimal amount of data to your jobs is the best approach.  Check out the 'Best Practices' section on the sidekiq wiki: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices

> What if your queue backs up and that quote object changes in the meantime?  Don't save state to Sidekiq, save simple identifiers. Look up the objects once you actually need them in your perform method.

Also in terms of reliability - *you should be worried* about your job queue going down.  It happens.  You either design your system to be fault tolerant of a failure or you find a job queue system that has higher reliability guarantees (but even then no queue system can guarantee 100% message deliverability).  Sidekiq pro has better reliability guarantees than sidekiq (non-pro), but if you design your jobs with a little bit of forethought, you can create jobs that can scan your database after a crash and re-queue any jobs that may have been lost.

How much work you spend desinging fault tolerant solutions really just depends how critical it is that your information make it from point A to point B :)